# Progress of all downloadable files using Firebase

Tags: swift, database, firebase, download, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to display an overall download progress. My current setup is, to loop over a snapshot, and for each item I am creating a download task, from where I can retrieve the `completedUnitCount`.

The issue I am facing is I can't find a way to determine the current progress, because each task is being run asynchronous.

I have a total of download size, 5Mb. but I

Ideally each download task adds up to each other, until the total of 5Mb is reached. And I know the download is done.

Am I thinking wrong, is there a better way for this?

Comment: So you have multiple items being downloaded at the same time and you want download progress of each one of them??

Comment: you could have a shared instance that each task updates with completed units, and then update the the progress display from the shared instance

Comment: That is interesting. I have lets say 200 items ready for download, and a for loop kicks all of them off at once. But I want to track their progress together. Instead of adding up all the mega bytes together, I can just add up the completed units. But the bar will be jumping and not smooth. Any other ideas?